# MAYA Standalone application and plugins

Tags: c++, maya

How can i load a maya plugin in a maya standalone application.
I tried to load it using

```
MGlobal::executeCommand("`loadPlugin \"C:/XXXXX/XXXX.mll\" `");
```

but each time i get

```
(kFailure) : unexpected internal failure
```

How can i do it properly ?

thanks,

Comment: I don't think you can load a plugin using another plugin. The best you can do is create an initializePlugin method that checks for your requirements and returns an error or a warning when the requirements are not satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

Have you already called

```
import maya.standalone
maya.standalone.initialize()
```

?  If not you don't actually have running maya instance to work in.

You can also load the plugin with maya.cmds

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
cmds.loadPlugin("pluginname.mll")
```

Comment: He is talking about c++ not python. Although yours could be an option I dont think is good to mix them.

Comment: you can create a standalone application using c++, and Yes i'm using MLibrary::initialize() which is the equivalent of maya.standalone.initialize() in c++

Answer (score 0):

The string that you're passing to MGlobal::executeCommand has backquotes around the command. That MGlobal::executeCommand call is running your loadPlugin command and then trying to run the return value of your loadPlugin command as another command.

It may be the case that your plugin loaded successfully, and the MStatus::kFailure that you see is the result of trying to run your loadPlugin command's return value.

Try removing the backquotes to see if that fixes the problem:

```
MGlobal::executeCommand("loadPlugin \"C:/XXXXX/XXXX.mll\"");
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but that doesn't fix the problem. i don't think that it has been loaded because when i try to execute a command registered by the plugin, it can't find it

Comment: Now i'm getting
`Error: line 1: Unable to dynamically load : C:/XXXXX.mll
specified module not found
Error: line 1: specified module not found
 (XXXXXXXXX)` i try to understand why when i execute the command in script editor it works, but in application it doesn't , did it need env paths ?